# Forgotten brace error when I use \left and \right

Tags: amsmath

I've a simple formula:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \displaystyle\sum\limits_{\mathclap{j \in \{1,2\}}}~\frac{q^{0} - q^{j}}{{(\norm{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2}})^{2}}
    \end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

After adding `\left` and `\right` commands to make the parenthesis of the denominator bigger, LaTeX generates the output as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \displaystyle\sum\limits_{\mathclap{j \in \{1,2\}}}~\frac{q^{0} - q^{j}}{{\left(\norm{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2}}\right)^{2}}
    \end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

but there is an error like `Extra }, or forgotten \right. ...orm{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2}}\right)^{2}}`. The code is seamlessly compiled without those `\left` and `\right` commands.

Comment: Replace it with:    `\displaystyle\sum\limits_{\mathclap{j \in \{1,2\}}}~\frac{q^{0} - q^{j}}{{\left(\norm{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2}\right)^{2}}}`. Simple rule: Respec the brackets ;)

Comment: You are enclosing `\left` in a group leaving out `\right`: `{\left( ... } \right)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many useless bits in your code

- inside `equation`, `\displaystyle` and `\limits` are already in force
- additional braces in the denominator can be disruptive of spacing
- `\mathclap` is not needed (and is wrong, as the need for `~` shows)

Here are my proposals (I'd go with the first one). Note that with my definition of `\norm`, `\norm*` is essentially the same as yours.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

%\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Good}

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j \in \{1,2\}} \frac{q^{0} - q^{j}}{(\norm{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2})^{2}}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Possibly preferable}

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j \in \{1,2\}} \frac{q^{0} - q^{j}}{\bigl(\norm{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2}\bigr)^{2}}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Possibly preferable again}

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j \in \{1,2\}} \frac{q^{0} - q^{j}}{\bigl(\norm{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2}\bigr)^{\!2}}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Disputable}

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j \in \{1,2\}} \frac{q^{0} - q^{j}}{\left(\norm*{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2}\right)^{2}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Grouping error in your code, below is the updated code:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \displaystyle\sum\limits_{\mathclap{j \in
    \{1,2\}}}~\frac{q^{0} - q^{j}}{{\left(\norm{q^{0} - q^{j}}^{2} - d^{2}\right)}^{2}}
\end{equation*}
```